# When user doesn't submit image to be uploaded, blob still stores in blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I allow 10 images to be uploaded at once (directly to the blob store).
image_i goes with text_i in the form.

not all content needs an image, so often image_i has no selected image file when a user submits the form.

I expected only blobs would get uploaded for the images (as that's what happens on the development server).

However when I went live, I saw heaps of empty blobs in the blob store corresponding to content length 0 images:

> Blob List > (application/octet-stream) 0 Bytes, 2012-08-14 17:11:54
>   AMIfv94Y7ie8cE84WZfEWGZw-NKJPE4iUaYn25zN1J-uftmoCESQoQFBimdiZr19suNBg_kUFW0P2frxIadmpd6LzPuFuA6o9UVq5UEqSvioXaBsDQeMwdJiH5gvh-8TtlZz8Rr1fRHHZd47zsiZpDiF1XsKa6A4aKTDvCnGEdMpW8lV6nlcFfU
>   Blobs with this content type cannot be displayed.

How do I prevent these? here is my code:

```
class AdminHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #displays a form that includes content1, img1, content2, image2..
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url(self.uri_for('image-upload-handler'))
        template_values = {'page_name': 'admin', 'upload_url': upload_url}
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('admin.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

class BlogPost(ndb.Model):
    date = ndb.DateProperty(required=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    blob_keys = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(repeated=True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty(repeated=True)
    content_order = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_blog_posts(cls):
        return cls.query().order(-cls.date)


class ImageUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        password = self.request.get('password', None)
        if str(password).lower() == 'cyclist':
            day = self.request.get('day', None)
            month = self.request.get('month', None)
            year = self.request.get('year', None)

            day, month, year = map(int, (day, month, year))

            try:
                date = datetime(year, month, day)
                #date = datetime.today()
            except ValueError:
                date = datetime.today()

            title = self.request.get('title', None)

            blob_keys = [i.key() for i in self.get_uploads()]
            #assert(blob_keys)
            content = []
            content_order = []
            for i in range(1, 11):
                content_i = self.request.get("content{0}".format(i), None)
                if content_i:
                    content_i = cgi.escape(content_i)
                    content_i = "<br />".join(content_i.replace("\r\r", "\r").splitlines())

                    content.append(content_i)
                    content_order.append("content_next")

                img_i = self.request.get("img{0}".format(i), None)
                if img_i and not "Content-Length: 0" in str(img_i):
                    content_order.append("image_next")

            #assert(content)

            blog_post = BlogPost()
            blog_post.title = title
            blog_post.blob_keys = blob_keys
            blog_post.content = content
            blog_post.date = date
            blog_post.content_order = content_order
            blog_post.put()
            ok = True
            success = "success"
        else:
            ok = False
            success = "wrong password"



<form action="{{upload_url}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
    Date day e.g. 31: <input id='day' type="text" name="day" /><br />
    Date month e.g. 12: <input id='month' type="text" name="month" /><br />
    Date year e.g. 2012: <input id='year' type="text" name="year" /><br />

    Title: <input id="title" type="text" name="title" /><br />
    Content1: <br />
    <textarea id="styled2" name="content1"></textarea>
    <br />
    Image1:<input type="file" name="img1"/><br />
    ...<br />
    {% for i in range(2, 11) %}
    Content{{i}}: <br />
        <textarea id="styled" name="content{{i}}"></textarea>
    <br />
    Image{{i}}:<input type="file" name="img{{i}}"/><br />
    ...<br />
    {% endfor %}
    password: <input id="password" type="text" name="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
    <div id="error-box"></div>
</form>
```

note I had to add  `and not "Content-Length: 0" in str(img_i):` when I went live because on the development server it's an empty string but on app engine it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4548), I suggest you add a star to it.

Until it is fixed, pretty much the options are to catch empty uploads on the client side and don't submit them, or in your upload handler delete blobs from the blobstore that have zero length.